# How to import a type from antd?

Tags: typescript, frontend, typeerror, antd

I want to import a type from antd-ui, like this

```
import {  StepsProps } from 'antd'
```

and then

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:30)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> > import { StepsProps as  } from "antd";
```

how could I do solve it?